# Can't store the instance of a window

Tags: c#, wpf

I build a class that allow me to extend the `NotifyIcon` to wpf, this working pretty well but I've a problem on a method that display a `BalloonTip`, let me explain how the class working:

```
public class TrayMinimize
{
  private Window _window;
  private NotifyIcon _notifyIcon;
  private bool _balloonShown;

public TrayMinimize(Window window)
{
     _window = window;
     _window.StateChanged += new EventHandler(HandleStateChanged);
}

private void HandleStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_notifyIcon == null)
    {
       _notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
       var icon = Properties.Resources.Favicon;
       _notifyIcon.Icon = icon;
       _notifyIcon.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(HandleNotifyIconOrBalloonClicked);
      _notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += new EventHandler(HandleNotifyIconOrBalloonClicked);
    }

     _notifyIcon.Text = "Hello world";
     var minimized = (_window.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized);
     _window.ShowInTaskbar = !minimized;
     _notifyIcon.Visible = minimized;

     if (minimized && !_balloonShown)
     {
        _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000, null, "Test", ToolTipIcon.None);
        _balloonShown = true;
     }
}

// Maximize the window on double click
private void HandleNotifyIconOrBalloonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
}

// Display a BalloonTip
public void DisplayBalloon(string title, string body = null)
{
    _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000, title, body, ToolTipIcon.None);
}

}
```

I've a public constructor that allow me to pass the instance of the window where I need to handle the notifyIcon. The `HandleStateChanged` check if the `notifyIcon` is valorized, if not, I set an icon, and the event for the `MouseClick` and `BallonTipClicked`.

Now for use the control, I simply do this:

```
private TrayMinimize iconTray; 

public MainWindow()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      iconTray = new TrayMinimize(this);
}

 private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        iconTray.DisplayBalloon("Test", "This is a test!");
 }
```

now the problem is that when the method `DisplayBalloon` is called, I get this exception:

> NullReferenceException

seems infact that `iconTray` is null, this also happean if I call the method on the Main. I don't understand why happean this, 'cause I use an object already created and setted with the window instance. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this method:

```
public void DisplayBalloon(string title, string body = null)

{
    _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000, title, body, ToolTipIcon.None);
}
```

You should instantiate _notifyIcon object before calling ShowBalloonTip method.

```
_notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
```

This is the reason for the exception.

Comment: Uhm, so I guess that this line: `_notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();` doesn't store the instance in `_notifyIcon` for the next access, right? If I declare a new icon I lost the instance of the window..

Comment: _notifyIcon object has to be instantiated to be able to call the method. So if I were you I will add this code in the constructor: if (_notifyIcon == null)
    {
       _notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
       var icon = Properties.Resources.Favicon;
       _notifyIcon.Icon = icon;
       _notifyIcon.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(HandleNotifyIconOrBalloonClicked);
      _notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += new EventHandler(HandleNotifyIconOrBalloonClicked);
    }

Comment: You can do that any way suitable for your scenario. But the most important thing is to make sure to initialize the object before using it.

Comment: Ok, I have an idea. Please put a break-point on the line, and check if the object _notifyIcon is null.

Comment: I fix init the control in the constructor.

Comment: Wonderful, keep going :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your exception is related with `_notifyIcon` object inside `TrayMinimize` class.

`_notifyIcon` is initialized in `HandleStateChanged`, but only when `_window` raises `StateChanged` event. Have you answered question - what if this event is never raised?

Btw. You create `iconTray` (which type is `TrayMinimize`) using `MinimizeToTray`. Is this typo or you missed something here?